# Why is composition done with inner functions in JavaScrirpt?

Tags: javascript, function, composition

I have been reading about composition but every tutorial I see does something similar to the following.

```js
const eater = (state) => ({
  eat(amount) {
    console.log(`${state.name} is eating.`)
    state.energy += amount
  }
});


function Dog(name, energy, breed) {
  let dog = {
    name,
    energy,
    breed,
  }

  return Object.assign(
    dog,
    eater(dog),
    sleeper(dog),
    player(dog),
    barker(dog),
  )
}

const leo = Dog('Leo', 10, 'Goldendoodle')
leo.eat(10) // Leo is eating
leo.bark() // Woof Woof!
```

Why do we need the **Eater function** to return the function we want to add as a property?

By extension, why do we need to send the **object** we want the method to be added to?

why not do something like the following?

```js
const eat = (amount) => {
  console.log(`${this.name} is eating.`)
  this.energy += amount
}

function Dog(name, energy, breed) {
  let dog = {
    name,
    energy,
    breed,
  }

  return Object.assign(
    dog, {
      eat
    }, {
      sleep
    }, {
      play
    }, {
      bark
    }
  )
}

const leo = Dog('Leo', 10, 'Goldendoodle')
leo.eat(10) // Leo is eating
leo.bark() // Woof Woof!
```

Comment: Your version is demonstrating object-oriented programming, not high-order functions.

Comment: High-order programming uses closure variables, not `this`.

Comment: @Barmar Do we try to avoid object-oriented programming with Composition? I thought we were avoiding inheritance.

Comment: neither of your code blocks seems to be common style in my experience.

Comment: It looks like they're trying to implement a mixin design pattern.

Comment: Can you please elaborate or give a link on what you mean about  "Common style". I still don't know a lot about javascript so I don't know what's considered common.

Comment: What I mean is I've never seen code written like either of your examples. You say that "every tutorial" does it like this, but I doubt it.

Comment: I said "Every tutorial I see" meaning when I search something like " Composition in javascirpt" or "Compoition or inheritance" the code seen follows the first style given. Hence the curiosity.

Comment: The definition of "function composition" is returning closures that capture variables from the outer function. Inheritance in JS is done using object prototypes.

Comment: But it's not common to combine composition with objects like that. A typical high-order function is something like `function added(x) { return function(y) { return x + y; } }`